# Are any BPF programs required for a sockmap?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I am writing a [sockmap BPF program](https://lwn.net/Articles/731133/) and I was wondering what the requirements of such a program are. A sockmap may have a [parser and a verdict program attached](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14-rc3/source/kernel/bpf/sockmap.c#L16) so my question is whether either program is required before a socket is added to the map and if both are not required then what's the behaviour when either program is omitted.

Some confusing related statements showing why I have this question:

- [If no BPF programs are attached the sock object may only be used for sock redirect](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14-rc3/source/kernel/bpf/sockmap.c#L20) - I assume this means the redirect is being programmed via some means other than the verdict program attached to the sock map itself?
- [It's important to attach SOCKMAP to both parser and verdict programs](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-blog/blob/master/2019-02-tcp-splice/echo-sockmap.c#L66-L69) - this implies both the parser and verdict programs are required i.e. one can't exist without the other?
- [recv_sock -> str_parser (parse_prog) -> verdict_prog -> skb_send_sock](https://gitlab.collabora.com/martyn/linux/commit/174a79ff9515f400b9a6115643dafd62a635b7e6) - this ASCII diagram also seems to imply that if the parse program is omitted the verdict program won't receive anything to act on?

Answer (score 1):

In the current implementation of sockmap, both parser and verdict program required for the operation. There is a place for optimization: if you skip the parser program, `skb->len` should be returned by default, but sadly, that is not implemented yet.

- No other way to program redirect except the verdict program. This is required, without that you can put programs into the sockmap, but nothing will happens, data transmission stops.
- More like attach parser and verdict programs to the sockmap. They only makes sense in this causal order.
- Yes, thats the case. So you should have a parser program, even with a simple `return skb->len` one.